# Shiny: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I am trying to show a scatter plot with shiny that involves filtering data through user clicks.
However, I get an error:

> Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors   [No
>   stack trace available]
>
> Warning: Error in renderUI: 객체 'data_available'cannot be found   [No
>   stack trace available]

I have no idea where things went wrong.
Below is my code for my shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data_events <- read.csv("Desktop/athlete_events.csv")
df.physical <-data_events %>% select(Height,Weight,Sex,Year,Sport) %>% 
filter(!is.na(Height),!is.na(Weight))
df.physical <-as.data.frame(df.physical)

ui<- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Distribution of Height/Weight for Each Sport"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Create a scatter plot of height/weight for every sport in the 
Olympics."),

  htmlOutput("sport_selector"),
  htmlOutput("year_selector"),
  htmlOutput("sex_selector")

)
,
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("olmypicphysical"))
  )
)
server=shinyServer(function(input,output){
  output$sport_selector = renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId="sport", label= "Sport:", 
choices=as.character(unique(df.physical$Sport))
    )})
  output$year_selector = renderUI({
    data_available=df.physical[df.physical$Sport == input$sport, "Year"]
    selectInput(inputId = "year", label="Year:", 
choices=unique(data_available$Year))
  })
  output$sex_selector = renderUI({
    data_available1=data_available[data_available$Year == input$year, "Sex"]
    selectInput(inputId = "Sex",label="Sex:", 
choices=unique(data_available1$Sex))
    data_available2=data_available1[data_available1$Sex ==input$sex, 
"Physical"]
    output$olympicphysical = renderPlot({ 
ggplot(data_available2,aes(x=data_available2$Height,y=data_available2$Weight)
)+ geom_point()+theme_classic()+labs(x="Height",y="Weight")
    })
  })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The dataset I have created, df.physical (type is list) looks like this:

[df.physical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9t7y.png)

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: The issue is with `data_available`: `data_available=df.physical[df.physical$Sport == input$sport, "Year"]` returns an atomic vector, meaning that `data_available$Year` is invalid. This problem persists in the subsequent references to `data_available` as well.

Comment: What you're doing is equivalent to: `mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6,"mpg"]$mpg` - which you'll notice throws the same error

Comment: To fix, I believe you can just remove the `$Year`, `$Sex`, etc. from `choices = unique(...)` lines

Comment: Hi,I tried your solution but the results I get after removing $Year $Sex, etc is not right. data_available is still apparently still missing and I dont get any choices in the sports section. Is there any other way?

Comment: its missing now because its not a global variable. You are using shiny entirely in the wrong way. Why not use `updateSelectInput`?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some issues with your code. Your question is about `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. Indeed, this is caused by your selection method. First you select a vector out of your data.frame and next you try to subset that vector again by the name that it had in the data.frame.

Basically you try to apply the same selection twice. Easy fix is to leave out the column name in the first selection:

```
data_available=df.physical[df.physical$Sport == input$sport, ]
```

In addition, I am not sure why you are using `htmlOutput` in combination with `renderUI`. If you want to update/limit your choices in a `selectInput` you can just use the function `updateSelectInput` in combination with `ObserveEvent`. This makes your application more readable, and less error prone.

**Working example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui<- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Distribution of Height/Weight for Each Sport"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Create a scatter plot of height/weight for every sport in the 
               Olympics."),
      selectInput("sport_selector", choices=c(''), label='Sport:'),
      selectInput("year_selector", choices=c(''), label='Year:'),
      selectInput("sex_selector", choices=c(''), label='Sex:')
      )
    ,
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("olympicphysical"))
  )
)

server<-shinyServer(function(input,output, session){
  df.physical = data.frame(Height=c(170,180),Weight=c(80,80),Sex=c('M','F'), Year=c(1992,2012), Sport=c('Basketball', 'Judo'))

  updateSelectInput(session, 'sport_selector', choices = unique(df.physical$Sport))

  observeEvent(input$sport_selector, {
    df.physical_subset = subset(df.physical, Sport == input$sport_selector)
    updateSelectInput(session, 'year_selector', choices = unique(df.physical_subset$Year))
  })

  observeEvent({input$year_selector}, {
    df.physical_subset = subset(df.physical, Sport == input$sport_selector & Year == input$year_selector)
    updateSelectInput(session, 'sex_selector', choices = unique(df.physical_subset$Sex))
  })

  observeEvent({input$sex_selector},{
    df.physical_subset <- subset(df.physical, Sport == input$sport_selector & Year == input$year_selector & Sex==input$sex_selector)
    print(df.physical_subset)
    output$olympicphysical = renderPlot({
      ggplot(df.physical_subset,aes(x=df.physical_subset$Height,y=df.physical_subset$Weight)
      )+ geom_point()+theme_classic()+labs(x="Height",y="Weight")})
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```